# Search for quotes with regular expression

Tags: python, regex, quotation-marks

I'm looking for a way to search a text file for quotes made by author and then print them out. My script so far:

```
import re

    #searches end of string 
    print re.search('"$', 'i am searching for quotes"')

    #searches start of string 
    print re.search('^"' , '"i am searching for quotes"')
```

What I would like to do

```
import re

## load text file
quotelist = open('A.txt','r').read()

## search for strings contained with quotation marks
re.search ("-", quotelist)

## Store in list or Dict
Dict = quotelist

## Print quotes 
print Dict
```

I also tried

```
import re

buffer = open('bbc.txt','r').read()

quotes = re.findall(r'.*"[^"].*".*', buffer)
for quote in quotes:
  print quote

# Add quotes to list

 l = []
    for quote in quotes:
    print quote
    l.append(quote)
```

Comment: Someone's trying to cheat their reading homework aren't they...

Answer (score 5):

Develop a regular expression that matches all the expected characters you would expect to see inside of a quoted string. Then use the python method `findall` in `re` to find all occurrences of the match.

```
import re

buffer = open('file.txt','r').read()

quotes = re.findall(r'"[^"]*"',buffer)
for quote in quotes:
  print quote
```

Searching between " and ” requires a unicode-regex search such as:

```
quotes = re.findall(ur'"[^\u201d]*\u201d',buffer)
```

And for a document that uses " and ” interchangeably for quotation termination

```
quotes = re.findall(ur'"[^"^\u201d]*["\u201d]', buffer)
```

Comment: Yeah... I have a habbit of of writing all cases in my re matches... I'll edit the answer to include the easier way.

Comment: Remember that not all strings are ASCII. Your character class probably includes all non-quote *ASCII* characters, but what about things like accented characters (which could legitimately appear in an author's quotes?) It's better to blacklist the specific character you don't want, rather than try to whitelist all the characters you *do* want.

Comment: Yes agreed, for Non-ASCII cases please extend the character class to include the Unicode classes.  See http://docs.python.org/library/re.html for more information on character classes and methods with `re`

Comment: I just run a test on a sample text file pulled from a PDF and found there is a difference in " and ”. I take it the latter would be a unicode character because nothing is printed out.

Comment: Ha thanks guys, main reason for posting in here was to get away from that damm page! Been in there all day trying things out... I reckon I would quicker using word find and replace 

Could you explain why there is 3 " in the solution?

So are “ ” unicode metacharacters?

Comment: One for the beginning of the quote, one for the end and the one in the middle means, all character but ".

Comment: Thanks luke you've been a great help

Comment: @lukecampbell I tried your unicode example today to see if it works but it only solves one problem to create another... the output onto console after running the above produces a garbled square 0 kinda like [] but together... What is going on?

Comment: I copied the character from this site and pasted it in python, those numbers are what it generated (confirmed again)  What system are you using?

Answer (score -5):

You don't need regular expressions to find static strings.  You should use this Python idiom for finding strings:

```
>>> haystack = 'this is the string to search!'
>>> needle = '!'
>>> if needle in haystack:
       print 'Found', needle
```

Creating a list is easy enough -

```
>>> matches = []
```

Storing matches is easy too...

```
>>> matches.append('add this string to matches')
```

This should be enough to get you started.  Good luck!

An addendum to address the comment below...

```
l = []
for quote in matches:
    print quote
    l.append(quote)
```

Comment: -1: the OP isn't really looking for static strings. Regex is justified in this case.

Comment: The OP didn't have the edit when I answered.  Originally he was looking for a single -, and calling it a quotation mark.

Comment: Cheers @jaime I had not notice this lurking down here...

so from the code at the top of page

`code
import re

buffer = open('bbc.txt','r').read()

quotes = re.findall(r'.*"[^"].*".*', buffer)
for quote in quotes:
  print quote


QL= []
QL.append(quote)
`
the above only appends the last quote printed

I have tried QL.append(quote in quotes)

and all i get is true statement

any Ideas?

Comment: sorry about the formatting have not sorted out how to add code `code`

Comment: It's hard to read, but it appears you need to move your list initialization above the for loop.  I'll edit my code above to help.

Comment: Geeso simple code but powerful, thanks @Jaime

for the example above it should read ---------------

for quote in quotes