# Replacing unquoted words only in Python

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to replace a word, however only when its not surounded by quotations.

For example
Replacing `Hello` with `Hi`

`Hello 'Hello' Nothing` → `Hi 'Hello' Nothing`

Since `'Hello'` is in quotes it does not get replaced, but the first `Hello` does because it is not wrapped with quotes.

Any help would be great!

Comment: double quotes or single quotes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501959/search-for-quotes-in-text-file-python-re/10502125#10502125

Use re.sub

Comment: What about `Hello 'Hello Nothing' Nothing`? Or `Hello this isn't going to 'work'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular expressions are awesome:

```
>>>import re

>>>expression = re.compile("(?!(\"|'))Hello(?!(\"|'))")
>>>expression.sub("Hi",'This string says "Hello" and Hello')

This string says "Hello" and Hi
```

The only problem with that is that it will also fail to replace "Hello and Hello", if that becomes an issue you can add specific cases for them.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [a regular expression](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) (not the only way, but I'd go with that).

```
In [2]: print s
Hello 'Hello' Nothing
In [3]: import re
In [4]: re.sub("(?<!')Hello(?!')", 'Hi', s)
Out[4]: "Hi 'Hello' Nothing"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'([^"\']|^)Hello([^"\']|$)', r'\1Hi\2', "Hello mate")
'Hi mate'
>>> re.sub(r'([^"\']|^)Hello([^"\']|$)', r'\1Hi\2', "'Hello' mate")
"'Hello' mate"
```

`'([^"\']|^)Hello([^"\']|$)'` means 'The string *Hello* surrounded by something different than a single or double quote, or at the beginning or end of the line'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re

def callback(match):
   rep = 'Hi'
   return match.group(1)+rep+match.group(2)

your_string = "Hello 'Hello' Nothing"
print re.sub("([^\']|^)Hello([^\']|$)", callback, your_string)
```

This will match the word `Hello` that is surrounded by anything except `'` (`^` in `[]` means anything but). I also added the `|^` and `|$` to match the word `Hello` that is in the end or the beginning of the string.

It will replace it by the first part in parenthesis along with Hi and the second part (whatever they are).

Answer (score 0):

Use the substring function find all the occurances of the word you want to replace, for each word look at one index previous to what the substring function returns and see if its a quote.

eg. ""Hello 'Hello' Nothing"

Substring function returns 0 -- so of course there is no quote
   Substring function returns 6 -- check string[5] -- theres a quote, look for next ocurance

How can you keep checking using the substring function? something like this:

```
startindex=0
while(!done):
      index=substr(string, startindex)
      if(str[index-1] == "'")
            startindex=index 
            continue
```

from here you'll figure it out

Answer (score 0):

This works for your test case.

```
import re
foo = "Hello 'Hello' Nothing"
mt = re.search(r"[^']Hello(\s+.*)", foo)
if mt:
   foo = 'Hi' + match.group(1)
```