# Regex Python~Get Everything In Between, If the word is not enclosed by single quotes

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replacing unquoted words only in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642346/replacing-unquoted-words-only-in-python)

This is what I have right now

```
found = re.match( r"hello[(](.*)[)]", word, re.M|re.I)
```

It will find:

```
Hello(here)  and give you "here"
```

I would like it to be able to do the following:

```
Hello  (Hi)
```

return the value even if there is whitespace on either side (but only white space, not other characters), So this would return "Hi"

```
'dfsfds Hello (Hi) fdfd' Hello (Yes)
```

this would return "Yes" because the first part is enclosed by single quotes, so we don't use that (the whitespace rule still applies here if possible)

EDIT:

```
 Hello  ('Hi')  would return 'Hi'
```

Comment: What about `Hello ('hi)xx')`? Do you need proper quote matching inside the parentheses?

Comment: Hello  (554)  would return 554

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/10642346/236871

Comment: That one is replacing, this one is getting. Also, there are differences between them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be perfect but this seems to satisfy your use cases.  I feel that this is quite an involved process, and with a few more rules it would start to approach the types of problems that regexes are *really* bad at.

```
>>> import re
>>> match_dict = {'hello(here)': 'here',
...                 'Hello   (Hi)': 'Hi',
...                 "'dfsfds Hello (Hi) fdfd' Hello (Yes)": 'Yes',
...                 "Hello ('hi)xx')": "hi)xx",
...                 "Hello  ('Hi')": 'Hi'}
>>> for s, goal in match_dict.iteritems():
...     print "INPUT: %s" % s
...     print "GOAL: %s" % goal
...     m = re.sub(r"(?<!\()'[^']+'", '', s, flags=re.I|re.M)
...     paren_quotes = re.findall(r"hello\s*\('([^']+)'\)", m, flags=re.I|re.M)
...     output = paren_quotes if paren_quotes else []
...     m = re.sub(r"hello\s*\('[^']+'\)", '', m, flags=re.I|re.M)
...     paren_matches = re.findall(r"hello\s*\(([^)]+)\)", m, flags=re.I|re.M)
...     if paren_matches:
...         output.extend(paren_matches)
...     print 'OUTPUT: %s\n' % output
... 
INPUT: 'dfsfds Hello (Hi) fdfd' Hello (Yes)
GOAL: Yes
OUTPUT: ['Yes']

INPUT: Hello  ('Hi')
GOAL: Hi
OUTPUT: ['Hi']

INPUT: hello(here)
GOAL: here
OUTPUT: ['here']

INPUT: Hello   (Hi)
GOAL: Hi
OUTPUT: ['Hi']

INPUT: Hello ('hi)xx')
GOAL: hi)xx
OUTPUT: ['hi)xx']
```

Comment: Hi, this works pretty well, but Ive made a small mistake, it should be case sensitive, so Hello would only work on Hello

Comment: Such as, to only find using 'Hello' not 'hello'

Comment: I assumed you wanted case insensitive, because you were using `re.I`.  With that flag removed, you can just change "hello" to "Hello" and be all set.

Comment: Awesome, it works. I was just wondering,  how could I change the ) bracket to something else? Maybe to )A ? I'm not that familiar with regular expressions (obviously). I tried editing your regular expressions but I had no success.

Comment: What do you mean the )bracket?  Like you want to match Hello (stuff)A? @user1357159

Comment: Well to be honest if you don't really understand regexes, you've jumped in way too deep with your current question.  For the most part you could probably try doing "\)A" instead of "\)" but really you're gonna need to build up some regex knowledge before you can edit all of this D:  For what it's worth, I couldn't write regexes at the start of this year.  Check out some tutorials, build a decent base of knowledge, and this will be a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove everything inside single quotes first:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "'dfsfds Hello (Hi) fdfd' Hello (Yes)"
>>> s2 = re.sub(r"'[^']+'", '', s)
>>> re.search(r'hello\s*\(([^)]+)\)', s2, re.I|re.M).group(1)
'Yes'
```

Comment: I have updated the question a little bit, and also I get an error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: This means the regex did not match anything.